# What does -p do when creating directories

Tags: utilities, mkdir

What does the following command do to my system?

```
$ mkdir -p /tmp/aes
```

I typed the following command into my command line and it executes as expected.

I know the folder is created as when I attempt to execute the line of code again, I get
the following error: `mkdir: cannot create directory /tmp/aes: File exists`

I can't see the folder on my desktop though.

I know `mkdir  /tmp/aes` will create a folder.

What is the function of `-p`?

How do I delete this unseen folder?

Comment: Why would that folder be on your desktop?? You've created it in /tmp.. Your desktop probably would be at /home/username/Desktop

Comment: @Nighpher oh yes I got confused between relative path and absolute path , what does -p mean anyway??

Comment: -p is used to create parent directories, if they don't exist..In your case, if tmp did not exist, it would have created that along with the aes directory.. check the man page if you have doubts like these

Comment: You are sure that calling `mkdir -p /tmp/aes` twice causes an error? That doesn't make sense as the task of `-p` is to prevent this error.

Answer (score 2):

From `man mkdir` :

```
   -p, --parents
          no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
```

Therefore `mkdir -p what/ever/directory` simply makes sure the directory exists. If it exists but without permissions for you, then the situation is difficult for you: you made sure the directory `what/ever/directory` exists, but it can easily happen that you can't use it because it has a different owner, permissions etc; the command `mkdir -p` won't throw any error in such case.

---

Anyways, the recommended way of creating temporary files in `/tmp` is using `mktemp` :

```
NEWTMP = `mktemp -d`
cd $NEWTMP
...
```

Comment: This is quite unclear: `what/ever/directory` contains 3 directory names, what does "simply makes sure the directory" exists mean in this context. What do you mean by being screwed? Doing `sudo mkdir -p /var/tmp/xyz/abc; sudo chmod 700 /var/tmp/xyz/abc; mkdir -p /var/tmp/xyz/abc' work perfectly fine and as expected, although I have no permissions for the 'abc' directory.

Comment: It doesn't exactly work as expected, because a freshly created directory by `mkdir -p` would have you as the owner, which is not necessarily the case when you call it on an already existing directory. Yes, the logic is clear and you are correct, but it's not what user expects when calling `mkdir -p`, hence the user is screwed.

Comment: **the recommended way of creating temporary files in /tmp is using mktemp** Well that really depends on what you're trying to do, where from and other things. Using *`mkdir`* for directories in *`/tmp`* is certainly useful very often. I do it quite regularly and I'm sure many others do too (those I know do anyway).

Comment: @Pryftan It's recommended that you use `mktemp` so that you are guaranteed to have a unique tmp directory instead of potentially 'making' an already created one, and overwriting some other tmp files.

Comment: @Major You missed the keywords 'depends on what you're trying to do'. Furthermore if it's not in a script there is no problem. Neither is there a problem if your script first removes the directory. There are other scenarios where you do not need to do that.  And as for 'overwriting some other tmp files' that's rather the point is it not? Temporary. So yes for some cases it's true it's better to use mktemp but it's not always necessary.